# Account not accepting password

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, password

On a 2015 MBP, just updated to Mojave and suddenly the password to my main account (the one I used to update) is not being accepted.

I've tried to reset it from my other administrator account, through running `resetpassword` in recovery mode –with both of these, the password changes successfully but when I try to login it is still not accepted–

and also trying `passwd` in single-user mode, in which case none of the old passwords are recognized.

Is there any way I can get back into my account short of transferring all the data to a new one?

Comment: Is there an Apple ID password associated with this account? What about a Filevault password?

Comment: You should try resting the user password by referencing the user ID instead of the Username. You can find your User ID in the user preference advanced settings. Also look into the directory utility but be careful and look at the user accounts. There may be some redundancy like “name” vs “Name” or a couple entry with a different user IDs

Comment: @MelvinJefferson Neither, I set up Apple ID but am not getting the option to reset it via Apple ID. Never set up filevault.

Comment: @Theologin could you please elaborate on this? I don't think I've tried this. What method would I use to reset it (single user, recovery, etc...)?

Comment: For example the first user created on macOS gets assigned user ID 501.  So instead of sudo passwd username it’s would be sudo passwd 501

Comment: @Theologin still doesn't work :(